# Connecting to a MAC address with PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt5, bluetooth-lowenergy, pyside, pyqt6

I would like to connect to a MAC address ( of a BLE dongle ) with PyQt or PySide.
I know that I need to create a controller and a mac address object but somehow it does not work.

```
def connect_to_mac(self, mac_address: str):
    self.current_device = QtBluetooth.QBluetoothDeviceInfo()
    self.controller = QtBluetooth.QLowEnergyController.createCentral(self.current_device)
    QtBluetooth.QBluetoothAddress(mac_address)
    address_type = QtBluetooth.QLowEnergyController.RemoteAddressType.PublicAddress
    self.controller.setRemoteAddressType(address_type)
    self.controller.connectToDevice()
```

Comment: What do you think that fourth line is doing?  You create a `QBluetoothAddress` object, but you then throw it away.  Did you mean to pass that to the controller?

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried multiple versions ... for example 

address = QtBluetooth.QBluetoothAddress(mac_address)
self.controller(address)

address = QtBluetooth.QBluetoothAddress(mac_address)
self.controller.createPeripheral(address)

...etc. None of them work. 

An actual working example would be more helpful!
Thanks

Comment: The key step you are missing is that you must pass the remote device address to `createCentral`.  You're mucking with the device address after you create the controller, and that's too late.

Answer (score 0):

Do things in the right order.  First, convert your mac address to a `QBluetoothAddress`.  Then, pass that to `QBluetoothDeviceInfo` to create a device info structure.  Then, pass that to `createCentral` and connect to the device.

I have not tried this, but this should be the right sequence:

```
def connect_to_mac(self, mac_address: str):
    addr = QtBluetooth.QBluetoothAddress(mac_address)
    device = QtBluetooth.QBluetoothDeviceInfo(addr)
    self.controller = QtBluetooth.QLowEnergyController.createCentral(device)
    self.controller.connectToDevice()
```

Comment: Runs into error ...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonProject\HemoGramDiag\comm.py", line 87, in <module>
    MyComm.connect_to_mac(mac_address=mac)
  File "C:\pythonProject\HemoGramDiag\comm.py", line 55, in connect_to_mac
    device = QtBluetooth.QBluetoothDeviceInfo(address)
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtBluetooth.QBluetoothDeviceInfo.__init__' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtBluetooth.QBluetoothDeviceInfo.__init__(QBluetoothAddress)

Comment: You also have to supply a name and a device class.  https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtBluetooth/QBluetoothDeviceInfo.html

Comment: thanks I read the docs but I need a working example because I tried so many variations and none of them work. Basically I just want to connect to a MAC address..